# How do I monitor all requests in an HttpClientHandler?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to debug some HttpClient authentication issues so I have:

```
var handler = new MyHttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myun", "mypw") };

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    await client.GetStringAsync("https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/myun/mypw");
}
```

where:

```
public class MyHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
}
```

but SendAsync() is only being hit once, where request is seen to contain the original request without the authentication details, and result contains the ultimate 200 response on successful authentication. How can I also see the initial 401 challenge response and subsequent request containing the credentials which must have occurred in-between?